# Moving to hbase 0.98.1-cdh5.1.3

Tags: maven, hbase

I am having a problem whose solution seemingly should be straighforward.

I have to move my maven based project from hbase (0.94.6-cdh4.5.0) to hbase (0.98.1-cdh5.1.3). Now what I see is that there is no jar file available at: [0].

This site [1] mentions that it should be the repo containing the jar.

I observe "pom" in the proposed dependency tag.

Can someone please tell me how to import this jar to my project?

[0] https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.98.1-cdh5.1.3/
[1] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.98.1-cdh5.1.3

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue, i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Oh yes - I am sorry for not updating it. You need to change your pom dependency from `dependency on hbase` to `dependency on -sub-jars- like hbase-client or hbase-server`. That is how I resolved it. These subprojects have their jars dependency available. Please ask if I am not clear enough.

Comment: Yup i figured that out...i have to explicitly provide dependency for hbase-client... Thanks for the quick reply though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the `pom` dependency from `hbase` to `-sub-jars-` like `hbase-client`, `hbase-server` and so on. These sub jars are available.

Happy running with hbase!